# How to perform fast searches on big TIBQuery dataset's using Delphi 5?

Tags: performance, delphi, dataset, delphi-5, locate

I'm working on an old Delphi 5 project which uses a `TIBQuery` dataset.

I need to close the dataset, remove it's master datasource, open the dataset again and activate the same record that was initially focused.

The dataset has 35 fields and 15.000 records and I'm having a performance loss while calling the `Locate` function (It takes about 1 minute and 35 seconds).

```
var
  PrevId : Variant;
begin
  //save the id
  PrevId := DstID.AsVariant;
  //close data
  Dst.Close();
  //remove the master dataset
  Dst.DataSource := nil;
  //load data
  Dst.Open();
  //go to the saved id
  Dst.Locate(DstID.FieldName, PrevId, []);
end;
```

I know that the main slowness cause is the big amount of records but it's not an aspect under my control.

I've tried using `DisableControls`/`EnableControls` but it doesn't had much impact on the performancies (Just 5 seconds less than before).

```
var
  PrevId : Variant;
begin
  Dst.DisableControls();
  try
     //save the id
     PrevId := DstID.AsVariant;
     //close data
     Dst.Close();
     //remove the master dataset
     Dst.DataSource := nil;
     //load data
     Dst.Open();
     //go to the saved id
     Dst.Locate(DstID.FieldName, PrevId, []);
  finally
     Dst.EnableControls();
  end;
end;
```

Is there some other optimizations for improving `Locate`'s speed with big datasets?

Comment: I don't know about IBX, but other controls can add in-memory indexes to speed-up locates. Look for an Index collection.

Comment: @MarcGuillot: It would be great but it seems that there isn't any property like that on the `TIBQuery` component

Comment: If the problem are the locates and not the retrieving of the 15.000 records, you can try filling those records within a Clientdataset (through a DatasetProvider), and index it to use for the local searches.

Comment: Since you search takes so long I'm assuming that your database probably doesn't have DstID field indexed. Acording to [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/IBX.IBCustomDataSet.TIBCustomDataSet.Locate) locate method should make use of database index if it is present otherwise it falls back to using Filters which is much slower. So I recommend you check your database to see if you have indexing enabled on DstID field. Also why don't you just store record number of the last active record before closing database instead of its value? ...

Comment: ... You could do this using [GetRecNo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.GetRecNo) method.